# date-fns and react - while loop adds 1 more day after checking given if statement condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-fns

I created a Calendar with React hooks, using date-fns,
following this article -> https://medium.com/@w.difulvio523/create-a-custom-hooks-calendar-in-react-e50bbba456e1

And added the functionality to display `schedules` which I fetch from my backend.

The logic is, if the `schedule` objects `date` is same as the `cloneDay`,
render the extra `Link` element where user can click and go to the matching `schedule` page.

The problem is that the `schedule` is being render on actual schedule day + 1.

ex. if the date is 14th, it will render on 15th

this issue is happening inside of the `cell` function

```
    const cells = () => {
        const monthStart = startOfMonth(currentDate) 
        const monthEnd = endOfMonth(monthStart) 
        const startDate = startOfWeek(monthStart, {weekStartsOn: 1}) 
        const endDate = endOfWeek(monthEnd)
        const dateFormat = "d" 
        const rows = []
        let days = []
        let day = startDate 
        let formattedDate = ""

        //here get the schdules
        //and render in cells.
        //if the schduels.date is same as 'day' or 'clone day', 
        //render <Link/> to Exercise element with corresponding ID

        while (day <= endDate) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                formattedDate = format(day, dateFormat) 
                const cloneDay = day
            
                //split and reforamt the cloneDay to compare with schedule object's date
                const formatCloneDay = cloneDay.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                // console.log('formatCloneDay', formatCloneDay)

                const scheduleElements = exerciseScheduleArray.map(schedule => {
                    //reformat for the compare with formatCloneday
                    const formatScheduleDate = schedule.date.split('T')[0]

                    const hasMatchingDays = formatScheduleDate.toString() === formatCloneDay.toString()

                    if(hasMatchingDays) {
                        //here it adds 1 day from matching day
                        return (
                            <Link className="schedule-link" to="/exercise/:exerciseId" key={schedule._id}>
                                <span>{schedule.bodySection} {schedule.duration}</span> 
                            </Link>
                        )
                    }
                    else return null
                })

                days.push( 
                    <div
                        className={`column cell ${
                            !isSameMonth(day, monthStart) ? "disabled" : 
                            isSameDay(day, selectedDate) ? "selected" : "" }`}
                        key={day}
                        onClick={() => onClickDate(cloneDay)} 
                    >
                        <span className="number">{formattedDate}</span>
                        <span className="bg">{formattedDate}</span> 
                        {hasSchedules ? scheduleElements : null}
                    </div>
                )
                //this will increase the day value by 1 each time it iterates
                day = addDays(day, 1)
            }
            rows.push(
                <div className="row" key={day}> {days} </div>
            )
            //if 7 days has been pushed to the rows, delete the days
            //so it could start a new row with new days
            days = []
        }
        return <div className="body">{rows}</div> 
    }
```

I track down the 'cloneDay' value and this `+1` behaviour happens inside of the `if` statement
where it checks the `hasMatchingDays`. Specifically here in `.map` function.

```
                const scheduleElements = exerciseScheduleArray.map(schedule => {
                    //reformat for the compare with formatCloneday
                    const formatScheduleDate = schedule.date.split('T')[0]

                    const hasMatchingDays = formatScheduleDate.toString() === formatCloneDay.toString()

                    if(hasMatchingDays) {
                        //here it adds 1 day from matching day
                        return (
                            <Link className="schedule-link" to="/exercise/:exerciseId" key={schedule._id}>
                                <span>{schedule.bodySection} {schedule.duration}</span> 
                            </Link>
                        )
                    }
                    else return null
                })
```

I wonder why it is causing that +1 day, and how can I render the schedule on correct date?

_

exerciseScheduleArray looks like this

[image]

Comment: At first glance it looks like you might be using a 1 based count for your schedule and a 0 base start for your week count. So your week days are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 - but your schedule days are 1, 2, 3 ... The code is a little hard to follow here, but these 'off by one' errors are often caused by the index starting at 0 or 1 when it should be the other, or they're caused by loops checking `<=` instead of just `<` (or vice versa).

Comment: Can you provide an example of your exerciseScheduleArray object?

Comment: @BrettEast Ah yes, I want the calendar to start from monday instead of the sunday, so I used the `let startDate = startOfWeek(currentDate, {weekStartsOn: 1})`, where I change the `weekStartsOn` value to 1. So this could be the problem?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto sure! I will edit and add on question

Comment: Hi @yoonvak, i copied the article code, then I paste your cell function, created a exerciseScheduleArray mock and looks like all worked well to me, showing the schedule link inside the right date. The only thing i did was set hasSchedules to always true, since i dont now how you get this value. So i believe we are missing something here.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Hey :) `const hasSchedules = exerciseScheduleArray.length > 0` this is how I check if there is a schedule in schedule's array. Hmmm is it ok if I share you my git page so you could see the whole code? -https://github.com/jjyoon7/exFetcherApp/blob/48f860872fa0b60cc7638d83a3a20cf214d5683d/ex-fetcher-app/src/components/Calendar/Calendar.js

Comment: Hi @yoonvak, take a look in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/luispaulopinto/pen/abNNmZa)

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Hey Luis :) when I checked the codepen, it still shows the schedule + 1 day. It renders from 16th, not 15th. But it does render from 15th in yours?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219851/discussion-between-yoonvak-and-luis-paulo-pinto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search,
I found the issue regarding date-fns UTC timezones.

As mentioned in this thread,
https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376

this might be the reason why the `cell` function would render schedules in correct date in USA, or same timeszones,

and would render day + 1, in t.ex Berlin.

For now, I will switch to moment.js to re-create the `cell` function as a solution.
Hope this helped ppl who encountered same issue as I did.

Comment: Note! It was still a same problem with moment.js, so I cannot really find what is the issue?

Comment: I know it's very late, but have you tried using a date tool that doesn't use the Date JavaScript object?